# how to reduce height if iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Google ad-sense code

```
<div id="opacity_ads" class="advertisment" align="center">
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:250px;height:250px;background-color: #FFF"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-8031746607239719"
     data-ad-slot="6445123983"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
```

The script is displaying the ads correctly.This script is creating an iframe code of `height:270px` and `width:480px`.because of this iframe code created in backend,only viewable on  console(iframe),below the advertisement,dynamic url are their,I am not able to click to that url because of this iframe generated by Google ad-sense script in back-end. How to prevent this iframe of how to reduce the height to 70px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of css in your css file:

```
iframe{ height: 270px;}
```

Try that.